# Is it ok to mix converter and extender cable with different amperes?

Tags: amperage

I have a charger for my laptop which needs a converter to hook up to local sockets.

On the converter it says 250V and 10A

I have an extension cable that says 250V and 16A

Is it ok to plug my converter into this extension cable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, can do that.
As long as the extension cable has a higher current rating that the load you attach to it, it is okay.

If instead you had a 16A load and a 10A extension cable, then it could be dangerous, as the cable could become hot, melt and catch fire, or set alight nearby objects.

The 16A that you can read on the label of the extension, is how much current it can safely conduct.
The 10A on the label of the power supply, is how much current it might require to work correctly.